# How to debug hanging emacs-async command?

Tags: org-mode, debugging, async

I'm trying to set up a function running on my timer to refresh my [org-gcal](https://github.com/myuhe/org-gcal.el) files by using the [emacs-async](https://github.com/jwiegley/emacs-async) library as follows:

```el
(async-get
 (async-start
  `(lambda ()
     ,(async-inject-variables "load-path")
     (require 'org)
     (require 'alert)
     (require 'request-deferred)
     (require 'org-gcal)
     (setq deferred:debug t
           async-debug t)
     ,(async-inject-variables
       "\\`org-gcal-")
     (org-gcal-fetch))
  'ignore))
```

However, when I actually run this, the `async-get` command (which waits for the async process to complete) hangs forever. When I run `org-gcal-fetch` in my normal Emacs process, it completes within a few seconds. Is there any way to set up a debug trace of the functions that are being run in the async process so I can debug where it's getting stuck?

Comment: Why are you passing ‘ignore to ‘async-start? Documentation suggests this tells the library that you don’t care about the returned future.